# Firebase Cloud Messaging iOS (compatibility with GCM server, topics)

Tags: swift3, google-cloud-messaging, ios10, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing an application on `iOS` which main purpose is to handle push notifications received from the server. Server is using `GCM` for messages delivery.

1. If I decided to use the `FCM` framework on iOS (not even decided, just haven't found GCM framework for Swift 3, nor on Cocoapods), how much compatible will it be with the existing `GCM` - **is it necessary to** **migrate it to FCM**?
2. Is it possible to **receive data messages** (not notifications - the work as the should) **while** **application is terminated**. While application is in the background or foreground, the delegate method is being invoked and data are handled as they should, but when it is terminated - nothing is invoked, only if user touches the notification popup, but I need to fill data from data message to the database even when app is closed.
3. How to determine the **`topic` to which the message was sent?**
   The reason I need this is that I have to make different actions based on to what topic/s the received message was sent to. I know that on Android, there is a key in received JSON - `from`, but what about iOS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. All the GCM features are compatibile with FCM (same token, topics etc).
   New FCM features might not be available in GCM.
2. On iOS is not possible to receive data-messages if the application is terminated (as in it's not listed in the app switcher menu). This is a limitation imposed by iOS.
3. for now I suggest to add (replicate) the information about which topic you are targeting in the the data payload of the message

Comment: And what if the app was terminated, I received some notifications, and I want that data to be loaded to application's database on the application start (kind of sync with the server)? The only way to do that is to get them directly from server using it's API?

Comment: I am not understanding your comment. If the app is terminated, it will not receive the notification. (point 2)

Comment: A possible scenario is the following: you send a data-message. If the app is terminated it will not receive the message. When the app is opened by the user, IF THE MESSAGE TTL IS NOT EXPIRED, the message will be delivered to the app.

Answer (score 0):

## Is it necessary to migrate it to FCM?

YES, and here is the [guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm) that can help you to migrate a GCM Client App for iOS to Firebase Cloud Messaging

## Is it possible to receive data messages?

Try to check this [page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) to know how the FCM message work. You can learn here all the possibilities that you can do with your message in FCM.

## How to determine the topic to which the message was sent?

Now, for this question, this [Topic Messaging on iOS guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/topic-messaging) can help you to answer your question.

Hope this information helps you.