# How to get the topic out of a Firebase message notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

In Android you can use `getFrom()` to read the topic from the notification. 
Can anybody help me how I can get to know this in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

The [`getFrom()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getFrom()) function in Android has no counterpart for iOS.

As a workaround, you can add in a custom key-value pair for the name of the topic you are sending the message to in your [`data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) payload.

This is also the suggested workaround mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42192436/4625829).

Answer (score -1):

In Appdelegate. Implement below function and you can get it in userInfo.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            // Access userInfo
            let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? NSDictionary
            if let aps = aps {
                let alert = aps["alert"] as! NSDictionary
                let body = alert["body"] as! String
                let title = alert["title"] as! String                    
            }

}
```